# How to work around this `Your connection is not secure` error in Firefox when using mitmweb?

Tags: firefox, proxy, mitmproxy

I am trying to use [mitmweb](https://mitmproxy.org/#mitmweb) as a proxy to audit some web front end performance issue.

However when I tried to connect to my work website, I got the following error:

[image]

Here is my proxy settings of Firefox:

[image]

Here is how I started `mitmweb`:

```
mitmweb -p 7999 --no-http2
```

I want to ignore this warning, but there is no 'Add Exception...' button available. How can I bypass this warning?

The OS is OSX 10.14.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a website has flagged `HSTS`, a properly implemented browser will honour the flag and will not allow the user to ignore the security risk.

Comment: Although if it's not preloaded, you may be able to get Firefox to forget its HSTS cache: https://superuser.com/questions/539580/how-can-i-remove-a-website-accidentally-added-to-firefoxs-list-of-hsts-sites and https://superuser.com/questions/1066863/how-can-i-add-a-certificate-exception-for-an-hsts-protected-site-in-firefox

Answer (score -1):

To bypass this warning in Firefox click on the blue "Advanced" button, then click "Accept the Risk and Continue".

Comment: The option is not available, as shown in the screenshot in the question